# Config PHP project in eclipse with apache server

Tags: php, eclipse, apache

I have tried to config the PHP project with apache server in eclipse pdt.
but I could not config.

There is one option of running PHP project in eclipse pdt,

[image]

we can run php project with built in php server, refer the image:

But PHP 7.4 is not running in php built in server, It shows the error as shown in image:

[image]

Help me to config and run php project in eclipse pdt with apache server.

Answer (score 0):

This is configurator for built-in php server: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

For local your local server you just need to create/open project that is part of your apache htdocs.